# Implement a Discover page with friends of friends

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables - User and Follows. The follows table defines two users, the user that is following and the user that is followed. Think of the idea like Twitter following.

I want to do a suggested people page. This will suggest followers of followers in order of their perceived relevance.

So if I have person A.

He follows person B and C

If person B and C both follow person D, and person B follows person E. Person D should come up of higher relevance than person E, and so on.

Can someone help me construct a query that would do this in the quickest way possible. Taking into account the potential of someone with a lot of followers.

Ultimately, I want a page that say - Check out these people: John is being followed by 4 of the people YOU follow.

A sample of my tables

```
public class User 
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Follow 
{
    public long FollowId { get; set; }

    public User Follower { get; set; }
    public User Following { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT - Current Query based on Patrick Mcdonalds answer

```
var query = from follow in db.Follows
            where follow.WhoIsFollowing == mee
            let friend = follow.WhoTheyAreFollowing
            from friendOfFriend in db.Follows
            where friendOfFriend.WhoIsFollowing == friend
            group friendOfFriend by friendOfFriend.WhoTheyAreFollowing into g
            where g.Key != mee
            select new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with something like the following:

```
List<Follow> followers = new List<Follow>();

var query = from follow in followers
            where follow.Follower.UserId == 1
            let friend = follow.Following
            from friendOfFriend in followers
            where friendOfFriend.Follower.UserId == friend.UserId
            group friendOfFriend by friendOfFriend.Following.UserId into g
            select new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

var suggestionList = query.OrderByDescending(f => f.Count).ToList();
```

Then you should probably filter out users you already follow, and also yourself. (If everyone you follow follows you back you will appear at the top of the suggestions)

**Edit**

Try something like the following to filter out yourself and your followers:

```
int me = 1;

var friends = from follow in followers
              where follow.Follower.UserId == me
              select follow.Following.UserId;

var query = from friend in friends
            from friendOfFriend in followers
            where friendOfFriend.Following.UserId != me
            where !friends.Contains(friendOfFriend.Following.UserId)
            where friendOfFriend.Follower.UserId == friend
            group friendOfFriend by friendOfFriend.Following.UserId into g
            select new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

var suggestionList = query.OrderByDescending(f => f.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I was after. Could I ask a quick question. I have edited the post to add what I have used based on your post, and works great. But any chance you can help to remove people that the logged in user is following? At the moment I run that query, and it comes with users that I (logged in user) follows, so I filter them out after

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your storage mechanism, you don't need to use "Follow" as an intermediary.

Consider this structure:

```
public class User 
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Following { get; set;}
}
```

Now you can easily retrieve who the person is following.

Lets say you have a `List<User> userList` and you want to search through them to find who's following User ID 5

```
var user5 = userList.Where(x => x.UserID == 5).FirstOrDefault();
var usersFollowingUserID5 = userList.Where(x => x.Following.Contains(user5));
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep with your current structure, you could do this:

```
var john = userList.Where(x=> x.Name == "John").FirstOrDefault();
var peopleFollowingJohn = followingList.Where(x => x.Following ==  john);
var peopleJohnIsFollowing = followingList.Where(x => x.Follower ==  john);
```